# Kotlin - local variables vs global variables

Tags: android, kotlin

You can declare a local variable without initializing or adding lateinit, but same is not true for global variable, my question is why ? why compiler do not give error for local variable too?

for example :

```
class A{

    var abc : String  // this is not allowed by compiler

    fun myOwnedFun(){
       var abcd : String // this is allowed 
    }

}
```

I understand one thing is allowed and the other is not but am curious as to why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scope of a local variable is the function where it's defined. The compiler has no problem verifying that a local variable has been initialized inside the function before it's accessed for the first time.

As for a public class field, the scope is infinite, hence the compiler has no way to ensure the field will be initialized before it's accessed. To prevent the program from getting into a bad state by using an uninitialized variable the compiler raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A{

    var abc : String  // throws compile time error

    fun myOwnedFun(){
       var abcd : String // throws compile time error while accessing it
       abcd. // throws error now, suggests you to initialize it.
    }

}
```

This is because Kotlin is built as a null safe language, which means all the variables must be initialized before using it, either as nullable which should be suffixed with `?` and assigned to `null` or with default constructor for any other classes, or use a `lateinit var` if you are sure that you will be assigning it somewhere before accessing it first.

In Android Kotlin, `lateinit var` is widely used for global variables which will be assigned in the lifecycle methods such as `onCreate()` etc.,

Comment: i am not accessing both. then one is writeable in code, and the other is not.
can write local variables without initializing but cant do the same for global variables without adding lateinit. why compiler doesnt complain when i create a local variable without a lateinit or "?"

Comment: @bawa The way I understand, global variable is throwing error on the same line because the compiler does not know where you are going to access it. For eg you can access the global variable inside the same class or in any other class.

But this is not case in local variables. You have to access it inside the function, and the compiler knows exactly where you are starting to access it. So the compiler suggesting you to intialize at the first access point.

Comment: yeah, i got that from egor's answer :D thanks for your input as well :)

Comment: "All variables must be initialized" is completely separate from null-safety.