# Why can I declare but don't initialize variables in Compose function with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I know I need to declare and initialize variables in Kotlin, such as `var hello="OK"`, or add keywork `lateinit` for `lateinit var str : String`.

The Code A can be compiled, but both `var mCoordinate: NewCoordinate` and `var temp: String` havn't been initialized, why?

**Code A**

```
  @Composable
    fun ScreenHome_Table(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        mViewMode: SoundViewModel
    ){  
        var mCoordinate: NewCoordinate  //It's OK        
        var temp: String                //It's OK        
        Box(
           ...
        ) {
           ...
        }
    }       
            
   class NewCoordinate(private val xOrigin: Float, private val yOrigin: Float) {  
      val Float.toX: Float get() = xOrigin + this                    
      val Float.toY: Float get() = yOrigin - this                 
   }
```

Comment: This is not Jetpack compose specific. It applies to all kotlin codes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin - local variables vs global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724567/kotlin-local-variables-vs-global-variables)

Comment: Closest explanation I could find -https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724692/9636037